# Resizing content blocks in concrete5

Tags: php, css, content-management-system, concrete5

I am very new to Concrete5 and CMS's in general, but I have managed to import an existing site into Concrete5 and I have learned how to add content areas into my html.

I have also added a few images to the database and added an Image Slider block, but it's enormous! The Image Slider takes up practically the entire page and I can't figure out how to resize it.

I have tried to create a custom class (slideshow-resize) with a width of 70% in my main css file.  I then added this to my `page_theme.php` file:

```
public function getThemeBlockClasses()
{
    return array(
        'Welcome' => array('slideshow-resize')
        );
}
```

but when I try to use this custom class on my image slider block, it doesn't show up as an option. How can I resize the image?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I shortened your question to get to the point quicker.  I find this site answers shorter questions faster.  Your question is well asked, so it is apparent you put some work into it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the proper way of doing it but I found a way to get this sorted.

in the folder concrete/blocks/image_slider there is a CSS file for it, I just edited that and hey presto! problem solved.

If anyone has a better way of fixing this issue though I would be very interested, I'm sure there has to be a way of doing this that doesn't involve editing core files.

I'm in the fortunate position that I'm only going to use the image slider once on this particular build but if I needed several instances of it, the above solution wouldn't work.